# Need a "HAS A" selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need a selector that says:

> Any table cell that has a checkbox in it

Right now, I'm using:

```
$('td input').filter(':checkbox').each(function() {
   $(this).closest('td').addClass('CursorPointer');
});
$('td.CursorPointer').on('click',function() {
   $('input:checkbox',this).click();
});
```

It works, but it might not be "best".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [the `:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [the `has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
// select all <td> elements that have a checkbox in them
$('td:has(input:checkbox)');
// same effect
$('td').has('input:checkbox');
```

Note that [`input:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) is equivalent to `input[type="checkbox"]` in Sizzle/jQuery.

Your code sample could be rewritten as:

```
$('td:has(input:checkbox)').on('click', function() {
  $('input:checkbox', this).click();
});
```

Or…

```
$('td').has('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $('input:checkbox', this).click();
});
```

Note that `.has()` is more efficient than `:has`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has Although `:has()` is slightly more readable IMHO.

Comment: While syntactically better, isn't calling `.has()` faster?

Comment: @melee `.has()` might be faster because it avoids Sizzle’s custom pseudo-classes (meaning that `qSA` can be used when available). OTOH, `.has()` does introduce an additional function call. Why not [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) it? ;)

Comment: @MathiasBynens I'm terrible at writing perf tests, haha

Comment: Ok, I gave it a shot, I'm not sure how I did at this, but feedback is welcomed! http://jsperf.com/hashas

Comment: @Melee I’ve edited your test and simplified it a bit. Also, apparently I created a similar test back in 2010: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `$("td:has(:checkbox)")` do what you want to do? Have you tried it?

Comment: With JavaScript, I always ask on StackOverflow because the solution is never one that I would have come up with on my own.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('td').has('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass('CursorPointer');
```

Here's an example **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ak6YA/)**.